# django database_options for specific database in settings

Tags: database, django, config

Just wondering if I can only apply [database_options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/databases/) to a specific database if multiple databases are defined in settings? And how???

eg. I have defined the databases like this:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {...},
  'db2': {...}
}
```

the ultimate goal is to set the connection timeout value for db2 database without affecting default database

Comment: What is the database backend you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

Btw, are you still using django 1.1 cos that's what your database_options link point to (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/databases/).

Comment: arggggg I got that link from google and never noticed it was for version 1.1

Comment: no worries. btw, you can always replace `1.1` with `1.2`, `1.3`, `1.4`, `1.5` or `dev` directly in the url on your browser address bar, to jump to the version of the docs you are looking for.

Comment: yeah I figured that out but was always aware of the specific version